# Sorting unique consecutive pairs of items in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I asked a somewhat lacking question before, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077677/sorting-consecutive-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list). In my hurry to write that question, I realised that I had, in fact, posed the wrong problem. And the excellent answer did not reflect the problem I am trying to solve. Alas, here is me trying again.

My data is contained in pandas dataframe (on a column). For the sake of this problem, assume that it looks something like so (where we use the numpy version of a small view of the dataframe):

```
array([['a', 125183.195],
       ['t', 125529.335],
       ['t', 125626.555],
       ['a', 125632.485],
       ['h', 125755.395],
       ['h', 125868.105],
       ['e', 125892.82],
       ['e', 126007.555],
       [' ', 126113.25],
       [' ', 126221.61],
       ['w', 126695.285],
       ['w', 126827.34],
       ['-', 127149.21],
       ['-', 127269.435],
       ['s', 127668.525],
       ['h', 127789.04],
       ['s', 127800.76],
       ['h', 127887.645]])
```

Let's call this whole array `D`.

Now, I have about 2000 of these arrays and each one has on average about 300-400 rows. So there is no massive need for performance here.

Back to our MWE list, we are only interested in ordering the array *using only the first column*:

```
array(['a', 't', 't', 'a', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', ' ', 'w', 'w','-', '-', 's', 'h', 's', 'h'])
```

Now the way the items in the list *should* be structured is that of consecutive pairs (but for data-collection reasons, they are not). So here is the sorted column we are aiming for:

```
array(['a', 'a', 't', 't', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', ' ', 'w', 'w','-', '-', 's', 's', 'h', 'h'])
```

This the problem: the columns contain *almost* sequential pairs of items (the numbers in the above example) but some of them are out of order and have to be moved back to their partner (see above). To add further to the problem, the second column in `D` is numerical, and those entries are unique, and they too need to follow the new reordering. So the final result, what we are aiming for, for this minimal example is:

```
array([['a', 125183.195],
       ['a', 125632.485],
       ['t', 125529.335],
       ['t', 125626.555],
       ['h', 125755.395],
       ['h', 125868.105],
       ['e', 125892.82],
       ['e', 126007.555],
       [' ', 126113.25],
       [' ', 126221.61],
       ['w', 126695.285],
       ['w', 126827.34],
       ['-', 127149.21],
       ['-', 127269.435],
       ['s', 127668.525],
       ['s', 127800.76],
       ['h', 127789.04],
       ['h', 127887.645]])
```

Hence what is important is the vertical order of the characters-pairs. Where they appear in the array is key to my problem domain, hence they can only be moved into the relevant pairs, but save from moving a member of each pair, the first pair member cannot move.

A few things to observe:

- Performance is not really a problem since they will only need to be sorted once.
- The out-of-order pattern is **not** consistent and things move around a lot in each column, what is important is that each item is mapped back to its partner.

  - The items in column one *always* appear as pairs.

I am looking for help with a method that can sort the rows of `D` into the required pair-sequential order. Thanks and apologies for my first misspecified question.

Comment: Does the order matter? I mean, does it matter if it puts the symbols first and then letters?

Comment: No, the horizontal order doesn't matter, but the vertical order (i.e. the order of the rows) is what is important. So either (symbols, numbers) or (numbers, symbols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to use as **key** an increasing value each time you seen a letter two times, i.e:

```
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['letters', 'value'])

def lookup(v, d={}, c=count()):
    if v in d:
       return d.pop(v)
    else:
       d[v] = next(c)
       return d[v]

df['key'] = df.letters.map(lookup)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   letters       value  key
0        a  125183.195    0
1        t  125529.335    1
2        t  125626.555    1
3        a  125632.485    0
4        h  125755.395    2
5        h  125868.105    2
6        e  125892.820    3
7        e  126007.555    3
8           126113.250    4
9           126221.610    4
10       w  126695.285    5
11       w  126827.340    5
12       -  127149.210    6
13       -  127269.435    6
14       s  127668.525    7
15       h  127789.040    8
16       s  127800.760    7
17       h  127887.645    8
```

Once you have the key column, just sort by it (and dropped it):

```
print(print(df.sort_values(by='key', kind='mergesort').drop('key', axis=1)))
```

**Output**

```
   letters       value
0        a  125183.195
3        a  125632.485
1        t  125529.335
2        t  125626.555
4        h  125755.395
5        h  125868.105
6        e  125892.820
7        e  126007.555
8           126113.250
9           126221.610
10       w  126695.285
11       w  126827.340
12       -  127149.210
13       -  127269.435
14       s  127668.525
16       s  127800.760
15       h  127789.040
17       h  127887.645
```

To preserve the order of appearance use a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) such as merge-sort (specified by the parameter `kind='merge-sort'`).

Comment: That is precisely it, the only problem I see with the above is the blank-space character. The numbers have to be strictly monotonically increasing (on the value column in your answer). And it looks like in the above approach (index 9 and 8) have swapped place. Otherwise, everything is increasing on the value as required. I.e. `126221.610` should come after `126113.250`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the column of strings you can do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 125183.195],
       ['t', 125529.335],
       ['t', 125626.555],
       ['a', 125632.485],
       ['h', 125755.395],
       ['h', 125868.105],
       ['e', 125892.82],
       ['e', 126007.555],
       [' ', 126113.25],
       [' ', 126221.61],
       ['w', 126695.285],
       ['w', 126827.34],
       ['-', 127149.21],
       ['-', 127269.435],
       ['s', 127668.525],
       ['h', 127789.04],
       ['s', 127800.76],
       ['h', 127887.645]], columns=["letter", "number"])
```

As the order matters and it has to be sequential, the solution I have come up is not pretty fine but it works:

- Create a new data frame
- Create a list of indexes put in the frame
- Loop over the frame appending elements and the first occurring pairs while
  avoiding indexes that have already been included

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["letter", "number"])
indexes = []
for i in range(len(df)):

    if i not in indexes:
        df_2 = df_2.append( df.loc[i,:])
        letter = df.loc[i,"letter"]
        indexes.append(i)

        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if ((df.loc[j,"letter"] == df.loc[i,"letter"]) and (j not in indexes)):

                df_2 = df_2.append( df.loc[j,:])
                indexes.append(j)
                break;
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 125183.195],
       ['a', 125632.485],
       ['t', 125529.335],
       ['t', 125626.555],
       ['h', 125755.395],
       ['h', 125868.105],
       ['e', 125892.82],
       ['e', 126007.555],
       [' ', 126113.25],
       [' ', 126221.61],
       ['w', 126695.285],
       ['w', 126827.34],
       ['-', 127149.21],
       ['-', 127269.435],
       ['s', 127668.525],
       ['s', 127800.76],
       ['h', 127789.04],
       ['h', 127887.645]], dtype=object)
```

Hope this has helped.

Comment: Sorry that is not what I am looking for. The order has to be maintained as per the example result in my question.

Comment: Sorry did not notice the four letter h. Should they go separately? The first two in the first pair and the second two in the second one? I mean there are two h pairs and they are not separable by identifier.

Comment: That's a neat way, though it looks like you are introducing more instances of 'h' (see above) which doesn't look correct.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the 'h's have to appear as they do in the model answer. The sequential order is again important :(